# Polynomials cannot be small in a large set

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, polynomials

Let $P$ be a degree $d$ polynomial where $d\geq 1$. Suppose $P$ has a root $x_0\in [0,1]$, and suppose that $\max_{x\in [0,1]}|P(x)|=1$. Is there a constant $C_d$ depending on $d$ only, such that for every $0<\epsilon<0.01$
$$
|\{x\in [0,1]:|P(x)|<\epsilon\}|\leq C_d\epsilon^{1/d}?
$$ 
Note that this is easy if $d=1$. Indeed, suppose $P(x)=a(x-x_0)$. Since $\max_{x\in [0,1]}|P(x)|=1$, there is $x_1\in [0,1]$ such that $|a(x_1-x_0)|=1$. Solving the inequality $|P(x)|<\epsilon$, we get $|x-x_0|<\epsilon/a$, and thus 
$$
|\{x\in [0,1]:|P(x)|<\epsilon\}|\leq 2\epsilon/|a|=2\epsilon |x_1-x_0|\leq 2\epsilon.
$$
But in higher dimensions, this seems much trickier.

Comment: I suggest you use $\varepsilon$ and never use the ugly symbol $\epsilon$ like everyone else. (It's a joke!)

Comment: What happened to the question I answered last night????

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes but, unfortunately, not in a satisfactory way (read the last
two lines just after the horizontal line).

We'll assume $P$ has only one zero of multiplicity $1$. 
Then $P(x)=(x-x_0)Q(x)$, where $x_0\in[0,1]$ and $Q$ is some polynomial which
doesn't vanish on $[0,1]$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $\alpha_0=\min_{x\in[0,1]}|Q(x)|>0$. If $x\in[0,1]$
satisfies $|P(x)|<\varepsilon$ then
$$
  |P(x)|=|x-x_0||Q(x)|<\varepsilon
  \ \Longrightarrow\ 
  |x-x_0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|Q(x)|}\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{\alpha_0}
  .
$$
Therefore 
$\{x\in[0,1]\colon\:|P(x)|<\varepsilon\}
\subseteq\{x\in[0,1]\colon\:|x-x_0|\leq\varepsilon/\alpha_0\}$ and we
have the estimate
$$
  |\{x\in[0,1]\colon\:|P(x)|<\varepsilon\}|
  \leq 2\varepsilon/\alpha_0
  .
$$
If we take $\varepsilon<1$ then necessarilly $\varepsilon^{1/d}\geq\varepsilon$
for $d\geq 1$, so that

$$
  |\{x\in[0,1]\colon\:|P(x)|<\varepsilon\}|
  \leq 2\varepsilon/\alpha_0\leq\frac{2}{\alpha_0}\epsilon^{1/d}
$$
Lastly, pick $C_d=2/\alpha_0$ and notice that our constant $C_d$
only depends on our given polynomial $P$.

When our polynomial has more than one zero in $[0,1]$ we proceed
analogously. Even multiplicity won't be a problem

---

As you can see, this argument ignores completely the exact value of the
degree of $P$ (as long as it is $\geq 1$) and also the fact that $|P(x)|\leq 1$
for $x\in[0,1]$. (Also the fact that $\varepsilon<0.01$ is unimportant here
as long as $\varepsilon<1$.)

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I would like to have the constant C_d to be independent of the polynomial. But thank you anyway!

Comment: Oops... I completely ignored that. Maybe you should have made more emphasis on that... Anyway, I think (I haven't worked it yet) this line of thought can help you give a counterexample in that direction since the constant above depends solely on the polynomial.

Comment: Just one little comment: the way you wrote the problem leads one to think the polynomial, once chosen, is fixed. Maybe you should write it in some other way to emphasize that the constant you're looking for works for arbitrary polynomials (but depends only on their degree).

Comment: I guess that if I read really carefully, I can see you're clearly asking $C_d$ to *only* depend on $d$... But still... there are some people, like me, who would fall for this unwanted trap!