# Polynomial with small hessian determinant

Tags: polynomials, plane-geometry, hessian-matrix

Let $P:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be a polynomial with no constant or linear terms, and with all other coefficients bounded by 1 in absolute value. Suppose its Hessian determinant is equal to $\epsilon Q(x,y)$ for some tiny $\epsilon$ and some other polynomial $Q$ with all coefficients bounded by 1 in absolute value. Then is it true that for some unit vector $u$, we have
$$
(\nabla\cdot u) P(x,y)=\epsilon^{1/2} C_d R(x,y)
$$
for some constant $C_d$ depending on the degree $d$ of $P$ only, and some polynomial $R$ with all coefficients bounded above by 1 in absolute value?

Edited: this question occurs in my research, where I need to consider the set where the Hessian determinant of a polynomial $P$ is small. There is one particular case which bothers me, namely, when $\det(D^2P)$ is of the order $O(\epsilon)$ in the entire $[0,1]^2$ but some coefficients of $P$ is large, say when
$$
P(x,y)=x^2+\epsilon^{1/2}y^2.
$$
In this case we see that $\partial_y P(x,y)$ is of the order $\epsilon^{1/2}$. However, as in the case
$$
P(x,y)=x^2+(2+\epsilon^{1/2})xy+y^2,
$$
all coefficients of $P$ are large, but taking $u=(1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2)$ also does the job. For a general polynomial with high order, this rotation may be difficult to find.

Comment: you should display some examples where your condition holds, and indicate some sources where this is discussed, at least as far as background

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you want is false, the example would be
$$ P = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 $$
where the Hessian derivative is zero.

If this example does not finish things, you should explain why.

Comment: seems related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654423/polynomials-cannot-be-small-in-a-large-set